# How can I stop using setxkbmap groups from snagging modifier keys?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb, awesome

I have several different keyboard maps that I can switch between to my heart's content using:

```
setxkbmap dvp
```

Then when I want another one:

```
setxkbmap ptf
```

Etc. This works, but I'd rather use the groups function so that I can  toggle between them using any of the group toggle bindings. It works just fine if I setup something like:

```
setxkbmap dvp,ptf -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

By itself, this works. The problem is it screws up the key bindings in my window manager (awesome-wm). I have <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> bound to a function that minimizes the focused window. After enabling a multi-layout group as above, this binding no longer works. Awesome simply doesn't even see the key. There are at least half a dozen other keys that  get snagged, but I can't find any function they are performing or any documentation about this happening. For the record I can still bind other key combinations (for example I can still bind <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> or even plain <kbd>n</kbd>).

What's going on here and how do I make it behave itself?

Comment: I hope [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35897/awesome-keyboard-layout-switch/293672#293672) might help :)